# unix echo string with underscore next to variable

Tags: linux, unix, echo

Is there a way to use `echo` to print text containing underscore next to a variable? For example:

```
$ var_name='foo'
$ echo "$var_name\_bar"
foo\_bar
$ echo "$var_name""_bar"
foo_bar
```

I would like to avoid multiple quoted strings in a single echo command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` works in this case (since `$var_name` stands alone):

```
$ var_name="foo"
$ printf "%s_bar\n" "$var_name"
foo_bar
```

Or use `{braces}` around the variable to disambiguate where the variable name ends within an interpolated string:

```
$ echo "${var_name}_bar"
foo_bar
```

Comment: Braces is the general answer (other than echo)